# How do I properly specify the SyntaxNodes for nameof to Roslyn when using the CSharp.SyntaxFactory?

Tags: c#, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree, roslyn

I'm currently writing a code generator that incorporates Roslyn, but am stuck on how to properly create the C# syntax nodes for the `nameof`operator. As an MCVE, I want to build the Syntax Tree for the following code and then compile it:

```cs
using System;

namespace CompilationTests
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public const string Bar = nameof(Array.Length);
    }
}
```

The using, namespace, and class declarations are no problem, but I can't get the invocation expression right. According to Syntax Visualizer and Roslyn Quoter, `nameof` is simply an `IdentifierName("nameof")` expression, and `Array.Length` is a `SimpleMemberAccessExpression`:

[image: Syntax Node Structure according to Syntax Visualizer]

I then tried to build up the syntax nodes for the field with the following code:

```cs
FieldDeclaration(
    VariableDeclaration(PredefinedType(Token(SyntaxKind.StringKeyword)))
        .WithVariables(
            SingletonSeparatedList(
                VariableDeclarator(Identifier("Bar"))
                    .WithInitializer(
                        EqualsValueClause(
                            InvocationExpression(IdentifierName("nameof"))
                                .WithArgumentList(
                                    ArgumentList(
                                        SingletonSeparatedList(
                                            Argument(
                                                MemberAccessExpression(
                                                    SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression,
                                                    IdentifierName("Array"),
                                                    IdentifierName("Length")))))))))))
.WithModifiers(
    TokenList(Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword), Token(SyntaxKind.ConstKeyword)))
```

However, when I create a compilation and emit it to a stream, it fails to resolve `nameof`and `Aray.Length`, giving the following compiler diagnostics:

```
(8,35): error CS0103: The name 'nameof' does not exist in the current context
(8,42): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Array.Length'
```

**But when I simply pass the source code to CSharpSyntaxTree.Parse as a string instead of creating the syntax tree on my own, everything compiiles just fine.**

**My question is : how can I create the syntax nodes for `nameof(Array.Length)` properly? Or am I missing some options when creating the syntax tree?**

For the sake of completeness, here is the full MCVE, simply paste it into an xunit test project that also references Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp (as of this writing, 3.6.0).

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;
using static Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory;

namespace CompilationTests
{
    public sealed class CSharpCompilationTests
    {
        private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;

        public CSharpCompilationTests(ITestOutputHelper output) => _output = output;

        [Fact]
        public void Compile()
        {
            var rootNode =
                CompilationUnit()
                   .WithUsings(SingletonList(UsingDirective(IdentifierName("System"))))
                   .WithMembers(
                        SingletonList<MemberDeclarationSyntax>(
                            NamespaceDeclaration(IdentifierName("CompilationTests"))
                               .WithMembers(
                                    SingletonList<MemberDeclarationSyntax>(
                                        ClassDeclaration("Foo")
                                           .WithMembers(
                                                SingletonList<MemberDeclarationSyntax>(
                                                    FieldDeclaration(
                                                            VariableDeclaration(PredefinedType(Token(SyntaxKind.StringKeyword)))
                                                               .WithVariables(
                                                                    SingletonSeparatedList(
                                                                        VariableDeclarator(Identifier("Bar"))
                                                                           .WithInitializer(
                                                                                EqualsValueClause(
                                                                                    InvocationExpression(IdentifierName("nameof"))
                                                                                       .WithArgumentList(
                                                                                            ArgumentList(
                                                                                                SingletonSeparatedList(
                                                                                                    Argument(
                                                                                                        MemberAccessExpression(
                                                                                                            SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression,
                                                                                                            IdentifierName("Array"),
                                                                                                            IdentifierName("Length")))))))))))
                                                       .WithModifiers(
                                                            TokenList(Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword), Token(SyntaxKind.ConstKeyword)))))))))
                   .NormalizeWhitespace();

            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                "MyAssembly",
                new[] { CSharpSyntaxTree.Create(rootNode, CSharpParseOptions.Default, isGeneratedCode: true) },
                new[] { MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Array).Assembly.Location) },
                new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
            );

            using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            var result = compilation.Emit(memoryStream);

            if (!result.Diagnostics.IsEmpty)
            {
                foreach (var diagnostic in result.Diagnostics)
                    _output.WriteLine(diagnostic.ToString());
                _output.WriteLine(string.Empty);
            }

            _output.WriteLine(rootNode.ToString());

            Assert.True(result.Success);
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public const string Bar = nameof(Array.Length);
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It has been 8 month, but for anyone searching for an answer:
The nameof identifier is not a normal identifier.
Instead of

```
IdentifierName("nameof")
```

you need

```
IdentifierName(Identifier(TriviaList(), 
                          SyntaxKind.NameOfKeyword,
                          "nameof",
                          "nameof",
                          TriviaList()));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're ever unsure how to express a given construct, you could always use the `SyntaxFactory.Parse*()`  methods to see how it would be parsed.

In this case, using `SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression("nameof(Array.Length)")`, it's an `InvocationExpression` (as it shows in your screenshot). Remember, `nameof` is a contextual keyword, it's not a reserved keyword. So its treated like any usable identifier, but has special meaning in certain contexts.  In this case, when used like a method invocation is interpreted as what we know as the `nameof` operator.

So to generate this expression using the syntax factory by hand, it would be this:

```
SyntaxFactory.InvocationExpression(
    SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("nameof")
)
.WithArgumentList(
    SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList(
        SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList(
            SyntaxFactory.Argument(
                SyntaxFactory.MemberAccessExpression(
                    SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression,
                    SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("Array"),
                    SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("Length")
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```